# How to make a Spring Data MongoDB GroupOperation on a single field but with an object as a result id?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Here is the group operation that I want to create depending on a nomenclature object.

```java
private static GroupOperation createStatsGroupOperationFromNomenclature(Nomenclature nomenclature) {
    Fields groupFields = Fields.fields("departmentCode");
    nomenclature.getDepartmentCode().ifPresent(code -> groupFields.and("subDepartmentCode"));
    nomenclature.getSubDepartmentCode().ifPresent(code -> groupFields.and("categoryCode"));
    nomenclature.getCategoryCode().ifPresent(code -> groupFields.and("subCategoryCode"));
    return group(groupFields)
        .count().as("nbProducts")
        .sum("$proposedMatchesAmount").as("nbProposedMatches")
        .sum("$reviewedMatchesAmount").as("nbReviewedMatches");
}
```

With the previous function if I provide a `departmentCode` and a `subDepartmentCode` inside the nomenclature parameter, here is the mongo query that is executed :

```
{
  _id: {
    "departmentCode": "$departmentCode",
    "subDepartmentCode": "$subDepartmentCode"
  },
  "nbProduct": {
    $sum: 1
  },
  "proposedMatchesAmount": {
    $sum: "$proposedMatchesAmount"
  },
  "reviewedMatchesAmount": {
    $sum: "$reviewedMatchesAmount"
  }
}
```

The result of this query are parsed in the following object :

```java
@Builder
@Value
public class ProductsStatsDocument {
  @Id
  Nomenclature nomenclature;
  Integer nbProducts;
  Integer nbProposedMatches;
  Integer nbReviewedMatches;
}
```

Problems append when I provide only a `departmentCode` inside the nomenclature parameter. Then the builded group operation has the following mongo query language equivalent:

```
{
  _id: "$departmentCode",
  "nbProduct": {
    $sum: 1
  },
  "proposedMatchesAmount": {
    $sum: "$proposedMatchesAmount"
  },
  "reviewedMatchesAmount": {
    $sum: "$reviewedMatchesAmount"
  }
}
```

And the result of this query couldn't be parsed to the previous `ProductsStatsDocument` because the result `_id` field id now a String and not a Nomenclature object.

Is it possible to force the `group` method to use an object as result `_id` field even with only one field ? Or is there an other way to build such a mongo group operation ?

=================================================================

Found the "why" of this issue. Here is a piece of code from spring data that transform the GroupOperation into a bson object :

```java
    } else if (this.idFields.exposesSingleNonSyntheticFieldOnly()) {
      FieldReference reference = context.getReference((Field)this.idFields.iterator().next());
      operationObject.put("_id", reference.toString());
    } else {
```

And here is the `exposesSingleNonSyntheticFieldOnly` method :

```
  boolean exposesSingleNonSyntheticFieldOnly() {
    return this.originalFields.size() == 1;
  }
```

As you can see, as soon as there is only one field to group on, it's used as `_id` result value.

Comment: Have you tried `group( Fields.from( Fields.field("departmentCode", "$departmentCode"), Fields.field("subDepartmentCode", "$subDepartmentCode") ) )`

Comment: hmm... `Fields.from` gives me a `Fields` wich is already what I have with `Fields.fields(...).and(...)`. So it works fine with `departmentCode` AND `subDepartmentCode` but not when I give only `departmentCode`

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: Yes I have. It works great when I pass departmentCode and subDepartmentCode but unfortunatly still doesn't work with only departmentCode for which departmentCode value is used as the id instead of creating an object containing the departmentCode. Anyway I miss read your first message and it was a good idea to try this solution !

Comment: ahh, ok let me know

Answer (score 0):

So finally the solution that seems to works for now is to create a custom AggregationOperation that manage the document transformation `_id` part :

```java
public class ProductsStatsGroupOperation implements AggregationOperation {

  private static GroupOperation getBaseGroupOperation() {
    return group()
        .count().as("nbProducts")
        .sum("$proposedMatchesAmount").as("nbProposedMatches")
        .sum("$reviewedMatchesAmount").as("nbReviewedMatches");
  }

  private final Nomenclature nomenclature;

  public ProductsStatsGroupOperation(Nomenclature nomenclature) {
    this.nomenclature = nomenclature;
  }

  @Override
  public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
    Document groupOperation = getBaseGroupOperation().toDocument(context);

    Document operationId = new Document();
    for (Field field : getFieldsToGroupOn()) {
      FieldReference reference = context.getReference(field);
      operationId.put(field.getName(), reference.toString());
    }
    ((Document)groupOperation.get("$group")).put("_id", operationId);

    return groupOperation;
  }

  private Fields getFieldsToGroupOn() {
    Fields groupFields = Fields.fields("departmentCode");
    if (nomenclature.getDepartmentCode().isPresent()) {
      groupFields = groupFields.and("subDepartmentCode");
    }
    if (nomenclature.getSubDepartmentCode().isPresent()) {
      groupFields = groupFields.and("categoryCode");
    }
    if (nomenclature.getCategoryCode().isPresent()) {
      groupFields = groupFields.and("subCategoryCode");
    }
    return groupFields;
  }
}
```

There is a bad thing about this solution: the overrided method `toDocument` seems to be deprecated.